# Double HTML Encoding with Google Apps Script HTMLService

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the Google Apps Script Html Service to render an HTML page.

The problem is that the HTML Entity gets displayed and not the intended special character. For example:

```
Miss McCleod's renders to Miss McCleod&#39;s  
view source is: "text-align: center\"> Miss McCleod&amp;#39;s
```

Rendering works correctly with

```
<code> <?=tune.tuneName?> </code>
```

but not with:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;"><?=tune.tuneName?> </h1>
```

where tune.tuneName is a member variable of an object that has been pulled from the Cache. The object was populated from a google spreadsheet and Utilities.jsonStringify() and Utilities.jsonParse() were used when putting and getting to/from cache.

The HTML templates script is shown below.

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;"><?=tune.tuneName?> </h1> 
<code> <?=tune.tuneName?> </code>

<div style="text-align:center;">    
  <? var imageUrl = getUrlForAttachmentFileName(tune.musicNotesImageFileName) ?>
  <img src="<?=imageUrl?>" alt="<?=tune.tuneName?>" align="center">
</div>
```

The following code is used to instantiate the page.

```
tuneRec = findTuneById(tuneId);  
var printHtmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('PrintPage');
printHtmlTemplate.tune = tuneRec;
return printHtmlTemplate.evaluate();



Miss McCleod&amp;#39;s implies that double encoding is taking place.
```

Any ideas on how to solve for the above would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<?!=` instead of `<?=` if you don't want escaping.