# Google Apps Script HtmlService template and URLs

Tags: google-apps-script

I giving a first shot at HTML templating with Google AppsScript and have had a pretty decent experience so far. My problem is that URLs are not being processed (replaced by "false")

My code.gs looks like this :

```
var section = HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('section')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

Logger.log(section.getContent());
```

and my html (section.html) :

```
<? 
var section = [
  {title: "foo",
   paragraph: "bar",
   url: "https://www.youtube.com/v=foobar"},
  {title: "foo2",
   paragraph: "bar2",
   url: "https://www.youtube.com/v=foobar2"}];

for (var x in section) { ?>

<h1><?= section[x].title ?> </h1>
<p><?= section[x].paragraph ?> </p>
<a href="<?= section[x].url ?>"> link </a>

<? } ?>
```

And the result of this (the log) :

```
<h1>foo </h1>
<p>bar</p>
<a href="false"> link </a>

<h1>foo2 </h1>
<p>bar2</p>
<a href="false"> link </a>
```

The same occurs for img' urls as well so I'm guessing there is a security notion here that I might be overlooking... Do you have an idea how to fix it?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Double HTML Encoding with Google Apps Script HTMLService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218538/double-html-encoding-with-google-apps-script-htmlservice)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind...

The issue was just improper force-printing syntax...

So if that happens to you in the future, your templating tags should look like this :

```
<?!= .... =>
```

and not

```
<? .... ?>
```

nor (that was my mistake) :

```
<?=! .... ?>
```